# Which file types and folders can be ignored for version control in MonoTouch

Tags: svn, xamarin.ios

We are trying to build our repository rules for MonoTouch 5.x and can't find any good guidance on which folders and file types can be safely omitted from the repository.

If there is a general guidance document available or can anyone provide details on the following files and folders:

```
Folders
  bin (already assuming this is not included)
  build (new to MonoTouch 5)
  obj (already assuming this is not included)

File Types
  .pidb
  .userprefs
  .plist
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's a .gitignore file used on the Xamarin MonoTouch Samples which would be a good set to use - https://github.com/xamarin/monotouch-samples/blob/master/.gitignore

Mostly it's .pidb, .userprefs and bin and obj folders.

You will need .plist files as these a just property lists and used to set information about your application and settings for your application.

I hope this helps,

ChrisNTR

Comment: Perfect! I also discovered (by having another developer checkout the code) that the new build folder IS required. I also found this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022111/what-are-monodevelops-pidb-files that describes the pidb files.