# What files should be included in .gitIgnore in MonoTouch projects/solutions?

Tags: git, xamarin.ios

I'm new to both MonoTouch and git.  I created a repo with my entire solution and noticed that some of the files have my user specific settings and others have Apple provisioning keys.  Should these be excluded from the repo?

Answer (score 3):

This should cover most of the things you don't need:

```
bin
obj  
*.user*  
*.pidb
```

Comment: Also, *.pidb files. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022111/what-are-monodevelops-pidb-files

Comment: This was still missing in the GitHub gitgnore projected so I added this as MonoTouch.gitconfig and did a Pull request for it just now. Hopefully available soon on https://github.com/github/gitignore

Answer (score 2):

I think that Rolf's response will handle most cases.  When starting from scratch [GitHub's Gitignore repository](https://github.com/github/gitignore) is a good place to start.

Assuming you are working on a Mac, you may also stumble upon OSX-specific files like .DS_Store.  You can find guidance on dealing with these environment-specific files under the [global](https://github.com/github/gitignore/tree/master/Global) folder (see the [Readme](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/README.md)).

Or you can just append the contents of multiple relevant files into your repository's .gitignore.  I'd recommend looking at:

- [CSharp.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/CSharp.gitignore)
- [Global/MonoDevelop.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/MonoDevelop.gitignore)
- [Global/OSX.gitignore](https://github.com/github/gitignore/blob/master/Global/OSX.gitignore)

Finally, if there is a chance that you will be sharing this code (e.g. making this a public repository on GitHub) and you had some private tokens in your userprefs file then you should consider re-initializing a new repository (with your new gitignore) or [purging](https://help.github.com/articles/remove-sensitive-data) the userprefs file from your history.

Answer (score -1):

My gitignore:

```
Thumbs.db
*.obj
*.exe
*.pdb
*.user
*.aps
*.pch
*.vspscc
*_i.c
*_p.c
*.ncb
*.suo
*.sln.docstates
*.tlb
*.tlh
*.bak
*.cache
*.ilk
*.log
*.pidb
*.user*
AppPackages*/
_UpgradeReport_Files*/
UpgradeLog.*
[Bb]in
[Dd]ebug*/
*.lib
*.sbr
obj/
[Rr]elease*/
_ReSharper*/
[Tt]est[Rr]esult*
```